# Why does code does not execute on server(filezilla) ,but execute on localhost when try to find out Internet Explorer version using php

Tags: php

I want to find out internet explorer version.Code run on localhost(wamp),but not on server(filezilla).Code is given below

```
    <?php

       preg_match('/MSIE (.*?);/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
    if(count($matches)<2){
      preg_match('/Trident\/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}; rv:([0-9]*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
    }

    if (count($matches)>1){
      //Then we're using IE
      $version = $matches[1];

      switch(true){
        case ($version<=8):
          echo "IE 8 or under!";
          break;

        case ($version==9 || $version==10):
          echo "IE9 & IE10!";
          break;

        case ($version==11):
          echo "Version 11!";
          break;

        default:
          echo "-";
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) is a FTP server. You need some webserver like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/).

Comment: You have to use servers like apache or ngnix

Comment: FileZilla is ftp server, wampp - web server. You need web server on both sides

Comment: How does it `does not work`? Any errors? Have you turned on error reporting? Is PHP versions same on localhost and on remote server? What does `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` contains on localhost and on server?